# R: merge two datasets within range of dates

Tags: r

I have one dataset `x` that looks something like this:

```
id  |      date
 1  |   2014-02-04
 1  |   2014-03-15
 2  |   2014-02-04
 2  |   2014-03-15
```

And I would like to merge it with another dataset, `y`, by `id` and `date`. But with `date` from `x` being same as or preceding the `date` in dataset `y` for every observation. Dataset `y` looks like this:

```
id  |      date      |   value
 1  |   2014-02-07   |    100
 2  |   2014-02-04   |     20
 2  |   2014-03-22   |     80
```

So I would want my final dataset to be:

```
id  |      date.x    |    date.y      |   value
 1  |   2014-02-04   |  2014-02-07    |    100
 1  |   2014-03-15   |                |     
 2  |   2014-02-04   |  2014-02-04    |     20
 2  |   2014-03-15   |  2014-03-22    |     80
```

I really do not have a lead on how to approach something like this, any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Where does `2014-02-08` come from in your final df?

Comment: @VitaliAvagyan Sorry, leftover typo from a longer version of example I had started posting. Changed it now. Thanks!

Comment: No worries. I posted an answer. Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 2):

This is easy in `data.table`, using the `roll`-argument

First, craete sample data with actual dates

```
library( data.table )

DT1 <- fread("id  |      date
1  |   2014-02-04
1  |   2014-03-15
2  |   2014-02-04
2  |   2014-03-15")

DT2 <- fread("id  |      date      |   value
 1  |   2014-02-07   |    100
 2  |   2014-02-04   |     20
 2  |   2014-03-22   |     80")

DT1[, date := as.Date( date ) ]
DT2[, date := as.Date( date ) ]
```

now, perform an update join on DT1, where the columns `date.y` and `value` are the result of the (left rolling) join from `DT2[ DT1, .( x.date, value), on = .(id, date), roll = -Inf ]`.
This code joins on two columns, `id` and `date`, the roll-argument `-Inf` is used on the last one (i.e. `date`). To make sure the `date`-value from `DT2` is returned, and not the `date` from `DT1`, we call for `x.date` in stead of `date` (which returns the `date` -value from DT1)

```
#rolling update join
DT1[, c("date.y", "value") := DT2[ DT1, .( x.date, value), on = .(id, date), roll = -Inf ]][]

#    id       date     date.y value
# 1:  1 2014-02-04 2014-02-07   100
# 2:  1 2014-03-15       <NA>    NA
# 3:  2 2014-02-04 2014-02-04    20
# 4:  2 2014-03-15 2014-03-22    80
```

Comment: This seems like it could do the trick. But I am getting an error: "Supplied 6605 items to be assigned to 6604 items of column 'date.y'. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() to make this intent clear to readers of your code." Not familiar with data.table so not sure how to read this. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: It probably gets multiple matches somewhere... you could try `DT1[, c("date.y", "value") := DT2[ DT1, .( x.date, value), on = .(id, date), roll = -Inf, mult = "first" ]][]`, setting the `mult`-argument to only return the `first` match found. See if the warning goes away. Make sure to check that the results are as expected!! I've had trouvbles with `mult`-and-`roll`-joins in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to `full_join` by ***year & month***.

Firstly we need to add an additional column that extracts month and year from `date` column:

```
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)

xx <- x %>% 
  mutate(y_m = as.yearmon(date))

yy <- y %>% 
  mutate(y_m = as.yearmon(date))
```

Then we need to fully join by `id` and `y_m`:

```
out <- full_join(xx,yy, by = c("id","y_m")) %>% 
  select(-y_m)

> out
# A tibble: 4 x 4
     id date.x     date.y     value
  <dbl> <date>     <date>     <dbl>
1     1 2014-02-04 2014-02-07   100
2     1 2014-03-15 NA            NA
3     2 2014-02-04 2014-02-04    20
4     2 2014-03-15 2014-03-22    80
```